# how to store a value from a specific point in an array to a register and vice versa in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

edit: this is using AT&T syntax

I am learning assembly using the GAS assembler and have to write a program where i compare the  int value in an array and change the value based on the comparison. I am writing it using inline assembly in C. I know that for a basic variable, say int i, i store the value in register eax with the following line:

```
movl i, %eax
```

but now say i have a variable a[2][2] and i want to move a[1][1] into %eax. the obvious wrong answer is:

```
movl a[1][1], %eax
```

and i get the error junk '[1][1]' after the expression. How do i go about moving the value of a 2d array into a register? thanks!

Comment: thanks for the tip, ill start doing that

Comment: You can either declare a variable before doing your inline assembler and store a[1][1] in it, otherwise you'll need to write your own bit of assembler to retrieve the value from the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you to turn the a[1][1] into a linear address. In other words, we have to take `a[1][1]` and figure out how far that is from the beginning of `a`. We start by figuring the size of a row -- in this case, 2 ints. So, (working in ints, for the moment) the beginning of row 0 is at offset 0 from a, row 1 at offset 2, and (if there were more rows) so on. We then add on the offset within that row. Finally, we scale that by the size of a single item.

From there, we have a couple of possibilities. One is that we just need a fixed position -- we're going to get `a[1][1]`, no matter what. The other is that we're really looking at `a[i][j]`, where `i` and `j` happen to be 1 at the moment, but could be other sizes.

For the first, we can use the fact that the assembler can do some math to compute the address for us.

```
// one row down times 2 ints per row + offset of 1 into last row, all times size of int
movl a + (1 * 2 + 1)*4, eax
```

In the second case, let's assume we have `i` in `esi` and `j` in `ebx`. In this case, we have to do the math ourselves (sorry, for the moment I'm going to use Intel syntax -- I'm just a lot more accustomed to it):

```
shl esi, 1    ; i * 2
add esi, ebx  ; i * 2 + j
shl esi, 2    ;(i * 2 + j) * 4

mov eax, a[esi]
```

The x86 can actually combine some operations like this that are common for addressing, so you don't have to execute them as separate instructions as I have above, so we could pretty easily reduce that to:

```
shl esi, 1
mov eax, a[esi][ebx]
```

That last may require a bit of explanation -- at least with MASM (and probably with gas, I'd guess) the assembler knows that since you're loading a value into `eax` that you're working in 4-byte quantities, so it automatically scales the offset by 4.

Comment: awesome man, this is exactly what i was looking for. When looking it up, all i could find was stuff for intel syntax. "movl a + (1 * 2 + 1)*4" was the answer. thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure on AT&T syntax so I'll post my Intel solution as well as my converted AT&T in case of confusion.

Basically, the value of the array needs to be looked up first, then possibly swapped.

### Intel Syntax

```
mov ecx, a  ;move the pointer to the 2D array into a register first
mov ecx, [ecx + 04h] ;walk to the a[1] dimension (4h happens to be the size of a pointer on my system)
mov eax, [ecx + 04h] ;eax now holds the value of a[1][1] and ecx still holds the memory location of a[1]
;do stuff with the eax register
mov DWORD PTR SS: [ecx + 4h], 1h ;change the value of a[1][1]
```

### AT&T Syntax

```
   movl a, %ecx
   movl 4%(ecx),%ecx
   movl 4%(ecx),%eax
   ; do stuff with eax
   movl $1,4%(ecx)
```

EDIT: Jerry's solution is probably better if you have a fixed-size array so you can calculate a linear address, but this will also work for dynamically allocated 2D arrays.